# Add/Remove nodes to Apache ZooKeeper cluster?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have ZooKeeper cluster with 5 nodes and multiple apllications will connect to it keep the application context settings. 
Due to some changes in the data center my network team want to replace 2 new VMs with existing 2 zookeeper vms. My questions are

1. Should I first add 2 new nodes to cluster?
2. Remove 2 exist nodes from cluster?
3. Do I need to restart all the connected applications with new cluster configuration?

If possible, please provide me order of action I should perform.
Appreciate your response.

Comment: are you saying they need to replace the VMs where 2 of the ZK nodes are currently running?